# IE 10 images not showing up

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-10

I am currently attempting to fix up the huge amount of issues that IE10 is causing when viewing my site.  [here](http://www.outlawsofhealth.com)  the current issue that's plaguing me is that all of my images are not showing up, at all.  Hoping to get soem help here. If any one knows of a site that has a list of fixes for IE problems that would be appreciated as well.

Taking for example one of the slider I am using I have just simple img calls

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
    <li><img id="imgMetrics"  src="jScroller/jScrollerImages/OutlawsOfHealthBanner.png" alt="Outlaws of health guys jumping" ></li>
    <li><img id="imgMetrics"  src="jScroller/jScrollerImages/tugOfWar.png" alt="Tug of war"></li>
    <li><img id="imgMetrics"  src="jScroller/jScrollerImages/welcome.png" alt="Welcome to the family image" ></li>
</ul>
```

Nothing to special, however IE10 just chews it up and spits it nothing out.

EDIT:: A fellow developer friend of mine, gave me some good ideas, it looks like it's a jQuery issue (Take the module away and it works) so now to work away it that. Thanks every one.
EDIT x2:: Alright so I've narrowed the problem down to my flash player, remove that call in my code and it works... so now it's just about figuring out where it's broken from there. If any one happens to see something I'd appreciate it.
EDIT x3:: fixed it, ended up being a conflict with some unnecessary js.

Comment: does it work with /jScroller/jScrollerImages/tugOfWar.png ?

Comment: This isn't your IE display problem, but you should not have multiple tags with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: IE10 generally follows rules and standards that previous versions did not, so there's a very good chance that you've got something invalid in your page that previous IE versions wrongly allowed, as opposed to something wrong with IE10. I'd suggest running your HTML through a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to fix any issues, and if that doesn't work, just start stripping away at your script, styles, and eventually your other HTML, until you see your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add this to the head section if something does not work in IE10 but it does in other browsers.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the same problem of images working in Chrome and Firefox and not working in Internet Explorer.

The problem was with the image and not with the code. I downloaded a .jpg and saved it as a .png.

Once I downloaded again as .jpg (and didn't try to change to .png) and changed in img src from .png to .jpg then everything was working fine in all the three browsers.