# Html images not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, html

My codes are working all browser except IE10.  I mean, it's working but not showing the images. I tried the solution here but didn't work-
[IE 10 images not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347817/ie-10-images-not-showing-up)

here are my codes-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="content type" content="test/html;sharset=iso-8859-1">
        <script>
            function myfun() {
                alert("you are here");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="next.gif" alt="image not found" onclick="myfun()" />
        <br/>NEXT
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't misspell `charset` and don't use ISO-8859 encodings this side of the year 2000.

Comment: Yeah, that `<meta>` tag is all kinds of jacked. `<meta charset="utf-8">` is all you need for an HTML 5 doctype.

Comment: Add height an width to the image

Comment: you don't need to self-close your `<img>` and `<br>` tags.  Thats's meaningless in an HTML5 document.

Comment: @Pointy It's [optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5), actually.

Comment: @AndréDion the parsers allow it but it has absolutely no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to click on ['Allow blocked content'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niMt9.png)

And, if this does not work, you could replace

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="content type" content="test/html;sharset=iso-8859-1">`  with

`<meta charset='utf-8'>`